# How to return Python exception info to jQuery.ajax POST call?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I make a JQUERY AJAX code in my HTML code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "runrep.py",
                data:
                {
                       'my_data' : 'test' 
                },
                success: function(html)
                {
                }
                error:function(xhr,err)
                {
                     alert("Failed\nreadyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status + "\nresponseText: "+xhr.responseText);
                }
});
```

In my backend code 'runrep.py' I have specifically trying to connect to a MySQL DB which is down.

When I run the program in Apache error_logs I see the DB unable to connect MySQL exception but the UI page does not renders any error?

```
class SampleClass:
        def __init__(self):
                self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",user="user",passwd="passwd",db="db")
                self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
                form = cgi.FieldStorage()
                self.my_data = form["my_data"].value
```

What should I do that I can print the program fault either be it exceptions, errors due to run time issue to browser / client side? Even if I catch the exceptions how can I return failure to AJAX call accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you should handle the exception in your code and pass it to the server code. For example, if you are using Werkzeug/Flask (see [the documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/)), you can do it this way:

```
import werkzeug

class SampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",user="user",passwd="passwd",db="db")
        except Exception as e:
            raise werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException("Error: %s" % str(e) )

        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()
        self.starttime = form["my_data"].value
```

The raised exception should be converted by the server framework to a proper HTTP response with some HTTP status code representing an error, such as 500. When an erroneous code is responded by the server, then you can handle it in the AJAX query.

Refer to your HTTP/WSGI framework for more information about exception handling and responses with error status codes.